# SQL to find duplicate records with values between 15 and 19

Tags: t-sql

I want to find SQL records which came second time(duplicate) with value between (15 and 19) and 90 days apart (dates doesn't need to be consecutive)

```
ChildID    Value     ValuetieredDate
1           15       2015-01-01
1           16       2015-04-01
1           2        2015-05-01
2           16       2015-01-01
2           17       2015-02-01
3           15.5     2017-08-01
3           17       2017-09-07
3           18       2018-01-03
4           16       2018-01-03
4           3        2005-01-03 
5           20       2012-02-01
5           16       2012-06-02
5           19       2015-09-08
```

I want to select CHILDID 1, 3,5
I tried

```
Select distinct ChildID,b.identifier,valueTieredDate,Value
,DateDiff(Day,lead(b.valueTieredDate) OVER (Partition by b.Childid order by b.valueTieredDate desc),b.valueTieredDate) as Datedif --Find consecutive dates
,DateDiff(day,First_Value(b.valueTieredDate) Over (Partition by ChildID order by b.valueTieredDate asc),valueTieredDate ) as Datedif1 --Not consecutive  
where value between 15 and 19.9
group by ChildID,b.identifier,valueTieredDate,Value
having count(distinct value)>1
From TestTable
```

Comment: What is your expected output on your provided data?

Comment: select CHILDID 1, 3,5

Comment: You have several rows with `CHILDID = 1`. Do you want to get all of them? And why rows with `CHILDID = 2` not in your result?

Comment: Ooops sorry Value (between 15 and 19) column with whichever date is >=90 days

Answer (score 0):

This should work if I got it correct

```
with cte (ChildID, Value, ValuetieredDate) as (
    select
        a, b, cast(c as datetime)
    from
        (values (1,15,'20150101')
        ,(1,16,'20150401')
        ,(1,2,' 20150501')
        ,(2,16,'20150101')
        ,(2,17,'20150201')
        ,(3,15.5,'20170801')
        ,(3,17,'20170907')
        ,(3,18,'20180103')
        ,(4,16,'20180103')
        ,(4,3,' 20050103 ')
        ,(5,20,'20120201')
        ,(5,16,'20120602')
        ,(5,19,'20150908')) t(a, b, c)
)

select 
    a.ChildID
from 
    cte a
    join cte b on a.ChildID = b.ChildID and a.ValuetieredDate < b.ValuetieredDate
where
    a.value between 15 and 19.9
    and b.value between 15 and 19.9
group by a.ChildID
having max(datediff(dd, a.ValuetieredDate, b.ValuetieredDate)) >= 90
```

EDIT: Just remove `GROUP BY` from query

```
select 
    a.ChildID, a.Value, b.Value, a.ValuetieredDate, b.ValuetieredDate
from 
    cte a
    join cte b on a.ChildID = b.ChildID and a.ValuetieredDate < b.ValuetieredDate
where
    a.value between 15 and 19.9
    and b.value between 15 and 19.9
    and datediff(dd, a.ValuetieredDate, b.ValuetieredDate) >= 90
```

Comment: Instead of those values can I use table? because my values are dynamic

Comment: 'With cte'  is just simulation of your table. Copy the part of query that starts with 'select' and change 'cte' with the name of your table

Comment: Hi this is working quite fine but small modification instead of getting highest or latest value tiered can we get the child id's with value between 15 and 19 and 90 days apart?

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte (ChildID, Value, ValuetieredDate) as 
(   select a, b, cast(c as datetime)
    from (values (1,15,'20150101')
                ,(1,16,'20150401')
                ,(1,2,' 20150501')
                ,(2,16,'20150101')
                ,(2,17,'20150201')
                ,(3,15.5,'20170801')
                ,(3,17,'20170907')
                ,(3,18,'20180103')
                ,(4,16,'20180103')
                ,(4,3,' 20050103 ')
                ,(5,20,'20120201')
                ,(5,16,'20120602')
                ,(5,19,'20150908')
         ) t(a, b, c)
)

select distinct cte1.ChildID 
from cte as cte1 
join cte as cte2 
  on cte1.ChildID = cte2.ChildID 
 and cte1.Value between 15 and 19
 and cte2.Value between 15 and 19  
 and DATEDIFF(dd, cte1.ValuetieredDate, cte2.ValuetieredDate) >= 90
```

Comment: Instead of those values can I use table? because my values are dynamic

Comment: It is the values you provided.  Feel free to test with a table.

Comment: Hi this is working quite fine but small modification instead of getting highest or latest value tiered can we get the child id's with value between 15 and 19 and 90 days apart?

Comment: @Hanu   It is returning the answer you posted.  SO is not a coding service.